# Search record and retrieve it from the database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my activity, I have editText's **(Username, Firstname, Lastname and Email Address)**. When the user input an existing username, he can search it by clicking the **Search Button** and the data which the user have will appear to the editText's.

MainActivity.java

```
btn_Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String searchableUser = txt_User.getText().toString();

        ConsUserRegistration consUserRegistration = db.searchUser(searchableUser);

        String searchUser = consUserRegistration.getUser().toString();
        String searchFirst = consUserRegistration.getFirstName().toString();
        String searchLast = consUserRegistration.getLastName().toString();
        String searchEmail = consUserRegistration.getEmail().toString();

        txt_User.setText(searchUser);
        txt_First.setText(searchFirst);
        txt_Last.setText(searchLast);
        txt_Email.setText(searchEmail);             
    }
});
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public ConsUserRegistration searchUser(String username){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_USER, new String[] {Constants.KEY_USER, Constants.KEY_FIRST, 
            Constants.KEY_LAST, Constants.KEY_EMAIL}, Constants.KEY_USER + " =? ", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(username) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ConsUserRegistration search = new ConsUserRegistration (cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

    return search;

}
```

But when the user click the Search Button and didn't input any character from the Username EditText, I am getting a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` error in the DatabaseHandler in line: ConsUserRegistration search = new ConsUserRegistration (cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

Also, I couldn't retrieve the data from the database since it's crashing.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. Just edited my question

Comment: nullPointerExceptions at which line of code ? See the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
db.searchUser(searchableUser);
ConsUserRegistration consUserRegistration = new ConsUserRegistration();
```

to

```
ConsUserRegistration consUserRegistration = db.searchUser(searchableUser);
```

Comment: Your suggested code is working however, when I didn't input Username, I am getting CursorindexOutOfBoundsException in DatabaseHandler in line: ConsUserRegistration search = new ConsUserRegistration (cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

Answer (score -2):

Button button_Search(button)findViewById(r.I'd.itsIdInYourXml);

Button probably needs declared or defined further need to see whole code